# The endpoint reference (EPR) for the Operation not found using glassfish n wso2esb

Tags: soap, wsdl, wso2, esb, wso2-esb

I am new to wso2 esb.
I am trying a simple web service program.

```
package testmart;

import javax.jws.WebService;

@WebService 
public class testone {

   public String testMethod()
    {
        return "success";
    }
}
```

I am using glassfish server, created a proxy on wso2 esb by giving following details:

web service url: `http://localhost:8080/testmart/testoneService`

wsdl url :`http://localhost:8080/testmart/testoneService?wsdl`

After creating its showing "success" msg. But when I test it, the following error comes up:

```
<soapenv:Fault xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:axis2ns7="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">

   <soapenv:Code>
     <soapenv:Value>axis2ns7:Client</soapenv:Value>

   </soapenv:Code>
   <soapenv:Reason>
      <soapenv:Text xml:lang="en-US" xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace">
 The endpoint reference (EPR) for the Operation not found is         /services/testmart1.testmart1HttpSoap12Endpoint and the WSA Action = null. If this EPR was previously reachable, please contact the server administrator.
 </soapenv:Text>
   </soapenv:Reason>
   <soapenv:Detail/>
  </soapenv:Fault>
```

Below is my esb source view code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

 <definitions xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
   <registry provider="org.wso2.carbon.mediation.registry.WSO2Registry">
      <parameter name="cachableDuration">15000</parameter>
   </registry>
   <proxy name="testmart1"
        transports="https http local"
      startOnLoad="true"
      trace="disable">
  <description/>
  <target>
     <endpoint>
        <address uri="http://localhost:8080/testmart/testoneService"/>
     </endpoint>
     <outSequence>
        <send/>
     </outSequence>
  </target>
  <publishWSDL uri="http://localhost:8080/testmart/testoneService?wsdl"/>
   </proxy>
   <sequence name="fault">
     <log level="full">
     <property name="MESSAGE" value="Executing default 'fault' sequence"/>
     <property name="ERROR_CODE" expression="get-property('ERROR_CODE')"/>
     <property name="ERROR_MESSAGE" expression="get-property('ERROR_MESSAGE')"/>
  </log>
  <drop/>
   </sequence>
   <sequence name="main">
       <in>
        <log level="full"/>
        <filter source="get-property('To')" regex="http://localhost:9000.*">
           <send/>
        </filter>
      </in>
     <out>
        <send/>
     </out>
     <description>The main sequence for the message mediation</description>
   </sequence>
</definitions>
```

I read all post about this error but could not solve this problem. 
Any sort of help would be highly appreciated as this was the first example I tried and stuck from hours.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

When you send the request check if the SOAPAction is set. If not, you can specify it in two ways:

1. ESB level

Set the property before the send mediator

```
<property name="SOAPAction" value="urn:SOAPAction" scope="transport"/>
```

2. Client level

You can specify the SOAPAction in the client side code. Specify it in the options as shown below.

```
options.setAction("urn:SOAPAction");
```

Answer (score 1):

in web interface from WSO2 ESB click "Source View" for your proxy and put this lines:

```
  ...
   <parameter name="serviceType">proxy</parameter>
   <parameter name="disableOperationValidation">true</parameter>
  ...
```

before the tag:`<description/>`

Answer (score 0):

You are using Wso2ESB, so you must need to specify like this:

@WebMethod(action = "testMethod", operationName = "testMethod")
public String testMethod()

The above annotation has to be used in the Web service implementation class.

Answer (score 0):

On Websphere Application Server, in the same situation, it helped deleting the Temp folders while the server was stopped.